# how to get value keyDown in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="text" id="name" onkeydown="myFunction()">

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    alert(name);
  }
</script>
```

when i entered "a" the system show empty, how can i get the value of KeyDown

Comment: onkeydown will trigger before the element has its value updated with the new key pressed. Maybe you should use the oninput event instead

Comment: Did you mean the documentation which has plenty of examples? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the function as follows:

```html
<div onkeydown="myFunction(e)" />
<script>
  function myFunction(e) {
    const key = e?.key; // Should have the key you've pressed in case enter you'll find 'Enter' as string
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    alert(name);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: doesn't answer the question by the way

Comment: Also, `name` will still not contain the pressed key.

Comment: updated the answer so that it isn't `undefiend` anymore.

Comment: Why are there curly brackets in your HTML?

Comment: @Cerbrus used to JSX fixed

Comment: `name` still doesn't contain the pressed key... This answer doesn't explain why

Comment: Toxic? You answered a simple duplicate with an incorrect answer. OP is getting `input.value` and is confused why that doesn't include the pressed key. _You_ added the new `key` variable, and didn't explain why.